# Sequelize use attribute field

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two models; giftModel and userGiftModel.
They are related to each other as follows:

```
userGiftModel.belongsTo(giftModel, { as: "gift", foreignKey: "giftId"});
giftModel.hasMany(userGiftModel, { as: "userGifts", foreignKey: "giftId"});
```

I count number of gifts for current user as userGiftCount and my goal is to return a status which is determined by userGiftCount.

Here is my query and the problem is that status always return 1.

```
    const gifts = await models.giftModel.findAll({
        include: {
            model: models.userGiftModel,
            as: 'userGifts',
            where: {
                userId: req.user.id
            },
            required: false
        },
        where: {
            giftStatus: 1,
            [Op.and]: [
                {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        {
                            giftStartDate : {
                                [Op.lt] : moment().unix()
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            giftStartDate : null
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    [Op.or] : [
                        {
                            giftEndDate : {
                                [Op.gt] : moment().unix()
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            giftEndDate : null
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        attributes: [
            ['giftId', 'id'],
            ['giftName', 'name'],
            ['giftDescription', 'description'],
            ['giftAmount', 'amount'],
            ['giftLink', 'link'],
            ['giftStartDate', 'startDate'],
            ['giftEndDate', 'endDate'],
            ['giftReportCount', 'reportCount'],
            ['giftReportSum', 'reportSum'],
            [fn("COUNT", col("userGifts.giftId")), "userGiftCount"],
            //here is my main problem
            [literal(`CASE WHEN 'userGiftCount' <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`), 'status']
        ],
        order: [
            ['giftId', 'desc']
        ],
        group: ['giftId'],
        includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
    })
```

Comment: Did you try to indicate `attributes: []` in `inlcude` for `model: models.userGiftModel`?

Comment: Still return 1 for all situations @Anatoly

Comment: Did you try to reproduce it in a simplified SQL-query? If so what results did you get?

Comment: No, i didn't. I just want to know how can i point to userGiftCount field.
when i try this :  `[literal('CASE WHEN userGiftCount <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'), 'status']` , i got this error : `SequelizeDatabase: Unknown column 'userGiftCount' in 'field list'` @Anatoly

Comment: It seems MySQL also can't use field aliases in expressions for other column aliases just like PostgreSQL can't. In this case, it's better to calculate `status` manually using query results or use raw SQL query